# What does the syntax C[1][x][y] mean?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, symbols

I am examining an integrability condition,
$$u_{3,122}=u_{3,123}.$$
Typing

```
DSolve[D[u3[x1,x2,x3],x1,x2,x2]==D[u3[x1,x2,x3],x1,x2,x3],u3,{x1,x2,x3}]
```

it into MMA gives the following output:

```
{{u3 -> Function[{x1, x2, x3}, 
C[1][x2, x3] + x1 C[1][x1][x3] + x1 C[2][x1][x2 + x3]]}}
```

I understand that the integration 'constants' `C[1]` and `C[2]` are functions of two variables, so the result `C[1][x2, x3]` is clear. But what does `C[1][x1][x3]` mean? Specifically, why is there a concatenation of argument brackets `[x1][x3]` instead of an argument?

Comment: I'm adding the [tag:bugs] tag because there should be three independent parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like an error.  For `C[1][x][y]` to make sense `C[1][x]` must represent a single-variable function (and `C[1]` should represent a function that produces a function).  However, in the solution returned by `DSolve`, `C[1]` has to have a different meaning in the first term.  Probably the second two parameters should be `C[2]` and `C[3]`.  Another point of confusion is that in classical math, `C[1][x][y]` would automatically be [uncurried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to form `C[1][x, y]`.  See also [`Curry`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html).

We can see that the more general expression with three functions `C[1], C[2], C[3]` is a solution:

```
D[u3[x1, x2, x3], x1, x2, x2] == D[u3[x1, x2, x3], x1, x2, x3] /.
  {u3 -> Function[{x1, x2, x3},
     C[1][x2, x3] + x1 C[3][x1][x3] + x1 C[2][x1][x2 + x3]]}
(*  True  *)
```

The uncurried form is also a solution:

```
D[u3[x1, x2, x3], x1, x2, x2] == D[u3[x1, x2, x3], x1, x2, x3] /.
  {u3 -> Function[{x1, x2, x3}, 
    C[1][x2, x3] + x1 C[3][x1, x3] + x1 C[2][x1, x2 + x3]]}
(*  True  *)
```

Speculation: Probably the parameter generator checks the heads for unique `C[n]` expressions, but the head of `C[1][x1][x3]` is `C[1][x1]` and doesn't match `C[1]`.  One can see that the order of creation with the following:

```
Trace[
 DSolve[D[u3[x1, x2, x3], x1, x2, x2] == 
   D[u3[x1, x2, x3], x1, x2, x3], u3, {x1, x2, x3}],
 C[_][__],
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

Remark: Note that `DSolve` gives an unexplainable error (without examining internals):

> Last::nolast: {} has zero length and no last element.

Comment: Just to compare. Maple 2018 answers $$ {\it u3} \left( {\it x1},{\it x2},{\it x3} \right) ={F_1} \left( 
{\it x3},{\it x2} \right) +{F_2} \left( {\it x3},{\it x1}
 \right) +{F_3} \left( {\it x1},{\it x3}+{\it x2} \right) .
$$